# Задача на системы счисления

Tags: c++, системы-счисления

Задача такая: нужно написать код который может значение с любой СС перевести в любое другое СС с 2-36 на с++, объязательно нужна строка для распознавание ошибок и интерфейс что бы можно было не выходить с консоли и через некоторое время опять ввести новые парамеры, в коде выходит одна противная ошибка `main.cpp:7:1: error: expected initializer before ‘int’ int main() ^~~` уже незнаю как ее еще можно пытатся исправить.

Код:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char* Dec2Numb(int N, uint8_t A, uint8_t B, char* buff)

int main()

{
  int idx = 0;
  char digit, temp[8 * sizeof(N) + 1];
  memset(temp, 0, sizeof(temp));

  // преобразование
  do
  {
    digit = N % B;
    N /= B;
    temp[idx++] = (digit > 9) ? digit + 55 : digit + 48;
  } while (N);

  // дополнение нулями до заданной длины
  while (strlen(temp) < A) temp[idx++] = 0x30;

  temp[idx] = 0;
  strcpy(buff, strrev(temp));
  return buff;
}
```

Comment: Точка с запятой пропущена: `;int main()`

Comment: Эта функция вообще не используется

Comment: @vp_arth я ввел эту точку с запятой перед int main() но теперь вышло еще больше ошибок

Comment: Попробуйте ещё `//` перед `char* Dec2Numb`

Comment: @vp_arth не помогает еще больше ошибок и все они одинаковые "was not declared in this scope"

Comment: @dIm0n пробывал убирать много ошибок появляются с "was not declared in this scope"

Comment: Я сдаюсь, тут нужны медиумы, а я джун

Comment: @Ram приведите [mre] ошибки, используя кнопку править

Comment: Скорее всего, «ещё больше ошибок» - это «ошибки, которые раньше не отображались, но они были»... Откуда импортируется, memset, например?

Comment: Ну так а где обьявление/определение `A`, `N`, `B`, `buff`, `strrev`?

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить, как делать перевод 2 - 36 СС. Я создавала переменную - ответ типа `string`, также вектор типа `char`, и туда клала "0" - "X". Далее, перевод осуществляется следующим образом: делите число на основание СС, в которую хотите перевести, и берете из вектора чаров элемент с номером `[остаток от деления]`, ну и дальше просто прибавляете его к переменной - ответу. Код, к сожалению, не приведу, поскольку не найду.